# Lotus Notes embedded view not working for one user

Tags: lotus-notes

I have an embedded view in a main form (same database) with a single category of a client code that is custom generated. The view displays all other documents that have that main document's client code in a hidden field.

This works perfectly, except for one user where the embedded view is blank, and the message `"category not found"` is displayed. This happens for all documents viewed. Anyone else that opens the exact same main documents can see the correct list in the embedded view. The documents are definitely there.

I've pressed F9 a few times, and the `"category not found"` keeps coming up. I've also shutdown Notes and deleted the cache file, and restarted. There have been no changes to the database for a long time, and this started for this one user a few days ago.

I have no idea whats causing this.

Comment: Do you use "Click on column header to sort" property of any column in that view?

Comment: Are you sure that the person is having access to read that document?

Answer (score 2):

Check readers/authors fields in documents that should be displayed in your embedded view. May be that user just can't see them.

Comment: Our readers and authors fields are set to Roles in the ACL, and these are set correctly for everyone.

Comment: @user1579279, check the option "Enforce a consistent Access Control List". May be it is switched off.

Answer (score 1):

Before I get too stressed, I generally try this:

```
Remove the database from the user's workspace
Compact the workspace (2nd tab of workspace properties)
Close Notes
Delete cache.ndk
Restart Notes
```

If that doesn't work, I'd check that the user can see the documents in another way (i.e. if you send a doclink to the user, can the user open it (alternatively, try opening the embedded view directly through View - Goto.  Don't forget to use CTRL-SHIFT at the same time if the view is hidden)?  If not, the user may have lost a role, or dropped out of a group that provides access.

Comment: I've tried now the compact workspace option as above, which didn't help. I also had the user open the original view, which they can - as well as open any documents in the view. I've also checked the ACL and even temporarily increased thier access level to no affect.

Comment: OK, next questions to sort out.  What is the formula for the Single Category? Is this on a local replica? If so, does the embedded view work for the user on the server?
If your working on the server, if you switch ID on the user's Notes client, does it then work?

Answer (score 0):

- ¿The view is "shared" and not "shared, private at first view"? In that case, you have to delete de "private version" of the view for that user
- ¿The embedded view is calculated, and show one view for a group of users and a second view for another group? Maybe you're searching the problem in the wrong view
- ¿The single category is based on a formula or on a calculated field? In that case, the formula calculates a different value for that user